# Why is the Digital Duel Disk not used in any Yu-Gi-Oh! series until Arc-V and Vrains?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In the *Yu-Gi-Oh Movie : Dark Side of The Dimension*. Kaiba introduce to all of Duelist a new Duel-Disk system, which have features to stored all of the card data that owner own to the `cloud server`/`data-center` of Kaiba Corp, So they didn't have to hold the card in their hand, the card just appears in their vision, probably using some like Augmented Reality thing, or we can say a *Digital Card*.

We know that the first generation of Yu-Gi-Oh series (Yugi Mutou) universe, still use a normal duel-disk. Even so in *GX*, we can clearly se Judai Yuki, the second generation of *Yu-Gi-Oh* still use the Normal duel disk. It contradicted with the timeline of *Yu-Gi-Oh* universe, because if Kaiba was introduce the new duel disk in Yugioh first generation, the new duel disk will be also appear in *Yu-Gi-Oh GX*, even *5D*, and *Zexal*. It's just appear in Yu-Gi-Oh Arc V and Vrains.

Could someone explain that to me ?

Comment: Are all of the series in the same universe though? I don't follow YGO at all, but I don't think *GX*, *5D*, and *Zexal* mentioned Yugi from the first series at all, making each series on its own universe...

Comment: @AkiTanaka in GX manga version, there is some flashback scene that show us the first generation of yugioh ( but just a flash of some character from the first generation tho ), and Judai yuki, the second generation, was inspired by all of the first generation, especially Yugi, except, in 5D, and zexal, as i recall, they never mention about their previous generation

Comment: @Wondercricket, but i would say this movie is a canon, because it's "roughly" explain many thing like, how could bakura get the millenium ring, Shadi's death, what happen to Anzu after the final battle with yami yugi etc

Comment: Speculation; Kaiba describes the technology as beyond bleeding-edge (not sure how that is described in the Japanese version). Perhaps it simply took a long time for the technology to be safe/cost-effective for mass-production?